# php require_once autoload.php causing 500 error

Tags: php, http-status-code-500

hi everyone I'm writing a code where I want to use the `autoload.php` and I had written it as

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require_once "database.php";
 require_once '/root/vendor/autoload.php';
 use Twilio\Rest\Client;
```

I'm using this code to run my `login_auth.php` this code is written in the top of the page, I don't know what is the issue is but if I run this code with terminal by command `php login_auth.php` this works correct and gives me the output I'm looking for, but if the same thing I run with postman https://demo.conitor.in/PageMyCell/login_auth.php  I'm getting error of `500 internal` server error, I'm not sure whether issue is with autoload.php or what, but here I'm using twilio so I'm using the autoload.php.

Comment: Check the error log. That is always the first thing you need to do when you get a 500.

Comment: hi @CBroe have error of permission denied `failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/PageMyCell/login_auth.php`

Comment: thank you @CBroe your comment made me to think about that, this solved my issue,  thank you very much

Comment: Also, please don't use irrelevant tags. The given problem is in no way related to Postman